# Badiou’s categorization of spheres of Truths

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, badiou

I’ve been reading through much of Badiou’s work for about a year and just finished *Being and Event*; though there is something I still don’t quite understand.

Badiou claims that the four spheres (of ontological situations) in which Truth events occur are Science, Art, Love and Politics. What I don’t understand is: why does he not include other spheres of thought/being? In particular, where does Philosophy fit in here? Is it not capable of producing Truths? What about Religion? (Though Badiou stays a staunch atheist, and I agree with him, so he may be denying the Truth producing capability of Religion there.)

I believe he had a strange set theoretic reasoning for this choice in his book *Theoretical Writings*, but I was’t quite able to understand it. Any help/discussion would be appreciated!

Comment: Arguably, religion might be seen to fall under the condition of “love”...

Comment: @JosephWeissman Arguably, religion might be seen to fall under the condition of “politics”...

Answer (score 4):

Welcome, Jacob. The following extract from Christopher Norris might throw some light on where the foursome derive from and how they do not exclude philosophy.

> ... one can best summarize by saying that any such [full] treatment would
>    involve consideration of the central role played in his thinking by four such
>    subject-areas. These are **mathematics** (in particular that modern branch of it
>    concerned with set-theoretical conceptions of the multiple and the infinite),
>    **the subject** (especially as theorized in the wake of Lacanian psychoanalysis),
>    **art** (where his commitments lie squarely with the more advanced or formally
>    adventurous modes of literary, visual, and musical production), and **politics**
>    (in which regard he has kept faith with the legacy of May 1968 and continues
>    to denounce every sign of what he sees as the 'Thermidorian' betrayal of that
>    legacy by the nouveaux philosophes and other media-sawy representatives
>    of mainstream French intellectual culture). **Such are the fourfold enabling
>    'conditions' of philosophy which Badiou defines more broadly as science,
>    love, art, and politics with science relating to mathematics in a fairly obvious way and love by no means reducible to but finding at least one partial means
>    of theoretical articulation in the discourse of psychoanalysis.** On the other
>    hand - crucially - philosophy must at all costs avoid becoming 'sutured' to
>    any one of those conditions whose exclusive or single-minded pursuit is then
>    apt to leave the philosopher exposed to the worst kinds of temptation, as
>    witness Heidegger's Nazism or (albeit in a very different, less plainly disas-
>    trous mode) the technocratic and un-self-critical scientism espoused by much
>    analytic philosophy. (Christopher Norris, 'Alain Badiou: Truth, Ethics and the Formal Imperative', Revista Portuguesa de Filosofia, T. 65, O Dom, a Verdade, e a Morte: Abordagens e
>   Perspectivas / The Gift, Truth, and Death: Approaches and Perspectives (2009), pp. 1103-
>   1136 : 1105-6.)

Hope this helps.